# Accessibility in Magento ce-1.7.0.2

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2

Can blind people use the current Magento store out of the box or what modifications are needed?

Are there any plugins for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer is NO.

Magento is not compatible with WCAG standards and there aren't any themes/plugins in the market to cover this aspect.

More info:

- http://www.w3.org/standards/techs/wcag
- http://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/consistent-behavior-consistent-functionality.html